# how to search by Categories in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

am using oscommerce v2.3.1
in this advanced_search. php  ,advanced_search_result.php i think  they Search by default Product_name
Product_model
Manufacturess_name

but i have to add one more field(Categories ) in this

here they are filtering the keyword

```
$keyword = tep_db_prepare_input($search_keywords[$i]);
          $where_str .= "(pd.products_name like '%" . tep_db_input($keyword) . "%' or p.products_model like '%" . tep_db_input($keyword) . "%' or m.manufacturers_name like '%" . tep_db_input($keyword) . "%'";
          if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['search_in_description']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['search_in_description'] == '1')) $where_str .= " or pd.products_description like '%" . tep_db_input($keyword) . "%'";
```

here i tried but not succeed please help me how to add that one

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$where_str .= "p2c.categories_id = '" . (int)$categories_id . "' and ";
```

after

```
$keyword = tep_db_prepare_input($search_keywords[$i]);
```

where $categories_id is the specific id of the category to be searched. Searching all sub cats is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The following contribution allows searching of the entire site. It adds the following features:

- Search in product descriptions
- Search in product attributes
- Search in language files
- Search in articles (if Article Manager addon installed)
- Search in pages (if Page Editor addon installed)
- If a search is performed on a word and no product matches are found, a form
  appears allowing the customer to email the shop owner asking for information
  about the product.
- A modified version of the Advanced Search Box is included. The price boxes and
  category selector can be enabled/disabled via settings in the 
  includes/boxes/search.php file.

download template from here: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/6351